# How to enable auto clean of pg_xlog

Tags: postgresql, wal, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to configure a PostgreSQL 9.6 database to limit the size of the pg_xlog folder. I've read a lot of threads about this issue or similar ones but nothing I've tried helped.

I wrote an setup script for my Postgresql 9.6 service instance. It executes initdb, registers a windows service, starts it, creates an empty database and restores a dump into the database. After the script is done, the database structure is fine, the data is there but the xlog folder already contains 55 files (880 mb).

To reduce the size of the folder, I tried setting wal_keep_segments to 0 or 1, setting the max_wal_size to 200mb, reducing the checkpoint_timeout, setting archive_mode off and archive_command to an empty string. I can see the properties have been set correctly when I query pg_settings.

I then forced checkpoints through SQL, vacuumed the database, restarted the windows service and tried pg_archivecleanup, nothing really worked. My xlog folder downsized to 50 files (800 mb), not anywhere near the 200 mb limit I set in the config.

I have no clue what else to try. If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I would be very grateful. If more information is required, I'll be glad to provide it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL won't aggressively remove WAL segments that have already been allocated when `max_wal_size` was at the default value of 1GB.

The reduction will happen gradually, whenever a WAL segment is full and needs to be recycled. Then PostgreSQL will decide whether to delete the file (if `max_wal_size` is exceeded) or rename it to a new WAL segment for future use.

If you don't want to wait that long, you could force a number of WAL switches by calling the `pg_switch_xlog()` function, that should reduce the number of files in your `pg_xlog`.

Comment: So patience is what was needed it seems. I did end up modifying my install script to include 'ALTER SYSTEM SET max_wal_size=20' before creating the database. That way, the px_log folder will not exceed 320 MB. Your answer sent me on the right path, so I checked it.

Comment: Just realized I also had to reload the config through SQL 'SELECT pg_reload_conf()'